# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: java, android, ssl, retrofit

I am getting this error

```
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I,am using Android SDK version 4.2.2,while my code is working fine with Android SDK version 8.

code

```
    public static Retrofit getClient() {

    if (retrofit == null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        Log.d("testing", "0000000");
        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
        okHttpClient = enableTls12OnPreLollipop(okHttpClient);


        final String authUserName = "@@@@@-###-***";
        final String authPassword = "*****";

        if (authUserName != null && authPassword != null) { // set authentication header if credentials available for accessing endpoints

            okHttpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    String credentials = authUserName + ":" + authPassword;
                    final String basic = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), "grant_type=client_credentials");
                    Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader(HTTP_AUTH_HEADER, "Basic  " + basic).addHeader("Content_Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(body).build();
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest);

                }
            });
        }
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient.build())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

public static OkHttpClient.Builder enableTls12OnPreLollipop(OkHttpClient.Builder client) {


    Context context = null;

    try {
        KeyStore ksTrust = KeyStore.getInstance("CRT");
        InputStream instream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.curl);
        ksTrust.load(instream, "secret".toCharArray());

        // TrustManager decides which certificate authorities to use.
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ksTrust);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        client.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return client;
}
```

and my log shows this

```
 *

D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x59ab at 0x08 in Lcom/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/Platform;.wrapSSLSession
    I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
    D/testing: 0000000
    W/System.err: java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore CRT implementation not found
            at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:119)
            at com.example.z00402fj.token.RetrofitClient.enableTls12OnPreLollipop(RetrofitClient.java:94)
            at com.example.z00402fj.token.RetrofitClient.getClient(RetrofitClient.java:59)
            at com.example.z00402fj.token.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:66)
    W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4206)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17357)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:818)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore CRT implementation not found
            at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
            at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
            at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:116)
            ... 14 more
    D/OkHttp: --> POST https://********/oauth/token http/1.1
        Content-Length: 0
        --> END POST (0-byte body)
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
        VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 24869: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0002
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
        VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 24868: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newInputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0002
    D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    D/OkHttp: --> POST https://*************/oauth/token http/1.1
        Content-Length: 0
    D/OkHttp: --> END POST (0-byte body)
    D/OkHttp: --> POST https://*********.io/oauth/token http/1.1
        Content-Length: 0
        --> END POST (0-byte body)
    D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

*

Answer (score -3):

Try using the latest TLS v1.2 in your Main Application class. This is provided via Google Play Services package, with the following code:

```
try {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
    SSLContext sslContext;
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
    sslContext.createSSLEngine();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException |
 NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Try this why, exactly?

Comment: I was facing same error and after running this i got no error for SSL.

Comment: i m also try this code earlier but its not work for me

Comment: @KartikShah now i solve this issue i answered my Question